# JAVA:How to print my CreditCard object's contents, instead of address? (I am printing the reference address)

Tags: java, object, printing, output

I'm working on an exercise in my Data Structures book, and it seems that I am printing the reference address instead of the actual contents? Can someone please take a look at my code and help me out? Thank you for your time.

```
public class CreditCard {
//  instance variables
private String customer;
private String bank;
private String account;
private int limit;
protected double balance;

// constructors - account for all cases, one with a bal, and one without
public CreditCard(String cust, String bk, String acnt, int lim, double bal){
    customer = cust;
    bank = bk;
    account = acnt;
    limit = lim;
    balance = bal;
}
public CreditCard(String cust, String bk, String acnt, int lim){
    this(cust, bk, acnt, lim, - 0.0);
}
// accessors
public String getCustomer(){return customer;}
public String getBank(){return bank;}
public String getAccount(){return account;}
public double getLimit(){return limit;}
public double getBalance(){return  balance;}

// updaters
public boolean charge(double price){
    if(price + balance > limit){
        return false;
    }
    else balance += price;
    return true;
}
public void makePayment(double amount){
    balance -= amount;
}

// utility (static)
public static void printSummary(CreditCard card){
    System.out.println("Customer = " + card.customer);
    System.out.println("Bank = " + card.bank);
    System.out.println("Account = " + card.account);
    System.out.println("Limit = " + card.limit);
    System.out.println("Balance = " + card.balance);
}
```

}// end class CreditCard

Comment: You need to add a `toString()` method for your `CreditCard` class. This method will override the same method in the `Object` superclass. It will also be implicitly called when trying to get a String representation of your object. By default, you get the result you seem to be seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you got was the [`toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--) implementation of class `Object`.
Quoted from its javadoc:

> The result should be a concise but informative representation that is easy for a person to read. It is recommended that all subclasses override this method.

That means, you need to override it with your own implementation of `toString()` in class `CreditCard`.
It can be as simple as this:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName()
         + "[ customer = " + customer
         + ", bank = " + bank
         + ", account = " + account
         + ", limit = " + limit
         + ", balance = " + balance
         + "]";
}
```

If you prefer multi-line output, you may insert some `\n` into the partial strings above.

By the way:
You don't need your method `public static void printSummary(CreditCard card)` anymore.
Instead of using

```
CreditCard.printSummary(creditCard);
```

you now can simply use

```
System.out.println(creditCard);
```

Under the hood that will call your `toString()` method.

Comment: Thank you. This was very helpful and educational.

Answer (score 1):

Add `toString` method (just override one).

```
public class CreditCard {
    //  instance variables
    private String customer;
    private String bank;
    private String account;
    private int limit;
    protected double balance;

    // constructors - account for all cases, one with a bal, and one without
    public CreditCard(String cust, String bk, String acnt, int lim, double bal) {
        customer = cust;
        bank = bk;
        account = acnt;
        limit = lim;
        balance = bal;
    }

    public CreditCard(String cust, String bk, String acnt, int lim) {
        this(cust, bk, acnt, lim, -0.0);
    }

    // accessors
    public String getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }

    public String getBank() {
        return bank;
    }

    public String getAccount() {
        return account;
    }

    public double getLimit() {
        return limit;
    }

    public double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    // updaters
    public boolean charge(double price) {
        if (price + balance > limit) {
            return false;
        } else {
            balance += price;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void makePayment(double amount) {
        balance -= amount;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("CreditCard{");
        sb.append("customer='").append(customer).append('\'');
        sb.append(", bank='").append(bank).append('\'');
        sb.append(", account='").append(account).append('\'');
        sb.append(", limit=").append(limit);
        sb.append(", balance=").append(balance);
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }

    // you do not need this util method because of it converts to
    public static void printSummary(CreditCard card) {
        System.out.println("CreditCard = " + card);
    }
}// end class CreditCard
```

Comment: Thank you! I had actually solved it just after I posted the question, but this was very helpful and educational.